# showing completeness of a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

$X=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $d(a_1,a_2)=|\ln(a_1)-\ln(a_2)|$. I have already proven that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, but I have some problems showing the completeness.

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy series in $X$, which means $|\ln(a_n)-\ln(a_m)| \to 0$ for $(n,m \to \infty)$.
Now I don't really know how to show that there exists an $a\in X$ such that $|\ln(a_n)-\ln(a)| \to 0$ $(n \to \infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a $d$-Cauchy sequence, then $\langle\ln a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in the usual metric, so it converges to some limit $L$. The limit of your sequence is related to $L$.

Comment: So I know that there is an L such that $lim |ln(a_n) - L| = lim |ln(a_n/exp(L))| = 0$ which means that $lim a_n/exp(L) = 1$, or $lim a_n = e^L$ for $n \to \infty$. Right?

Comment: @Val: Yes, that's right.